# What is Xbox Gold, and can I complete Xbox downloads through my computer?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I just bought an Xbox 360 and just realised how clueless I am about this. I received a deal to download a game from Xbox Live, but the problem is, my house does not have any WiFi.

So I was wondering if it would be possible to download the game using my laptop, and transfer it to a USB stick, then copy it to the Xbox?

In addition to the game, I received a one month gold subscription. What does that mean?

Comment: You might receive better answers if you asked the "gold membership" question as a seperate question, it's generally discouraged to ask two unrelated questions in a single question.

Answer (score 2):

Your 360 also has a port for an ethernet cable which you can plug directly into the same cable your laptop uses for internet.

Alternatively your laptop may come equipped with the ability to become a *Wi-Fi Hotspot* which lets it share the wired connection out over Wi-Fi, which your 360 could then connect to. A quick search gave me this: http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Your-Laptop-As-an-Xbox-Wireless-Adapter

Xbox gold is the paid subscription required to play games online. It also gives you other benefits, such as cloud storage for saves, and free games through the "games for gold" system.

Comment: The hotspot is super easy with windows 8 and pretty easy with windows 7, with XP or lower it's possible but kinda difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can not download the game via computer, as you need to be using the Xbox operating system in order too access the Microsoft Store giving you access to the game.

Xbox Gold is the subscription service required to play games online. The first month is free, and then it generally follows a pay structure of $20 for 2 months, $80 for a year.

Having a gold membership also entitles you to access the "Games for Gold" feature. Every month, a different set of games and add-ons get a special discount. On top of that, two games are offered for free.

Once you have started downloading any games for gold title, it is saved to your account. So you can literally start a download on a free game, cancel it, and access it in 6 months free of charge. So it is a good idea to work out your WiFi.

At the moment, [I believe the game is Plants vs Zombies](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/games-with-gold).

I would recommend investing $50 in a WiFi router. Alternatively, you can get long reels of ethernet cable cheap. A long cable running from one side of the house to the other may not be ideal, but you may be able to set it up for downloading games, and unplug it if your not using it.

Comment: You can "purchase" the free games each month from the website. I do this every month for both 360 and One titles, and then download them later on my 360.(I haven't purchased an XBox One yet, but I'm building a nice library for when I do get one).

Comment: Protip: LIVE gold subscriptions go on sale. You can get codes or physical cards with redemption codes from **reputable** vendors at multiple times throughout the year.

Comment: IIRC You need GOLD to use e.g. Netflix also (even if you already have a netflix subscription)

Comment: @Yorik I believe this is no longer true. As of mid 2014, Xbox Live Gold is no longer needed to play Netflix.

Reference: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/xbox-live-membership/live-faq?icid=furl_livefaq

Comment: @ragnarswanson: good to know

Answer (score -1):

**Downloading Games:** Your laptop apparently has internet access.  So do the same as you do to your laptop to get internet access to your Xbox console.  This might be:

- Plugging the network cable into the Xbox instead of the laptop.
- Taking the Xbox into the coffee shop, library or wherever you need to go to access the internet with your laptop.  BTW, you'll only need a monitor/tv for setting up the Xbox initially to access the internet and your microsoft account.  After that the Xbox can automatically download queued content without the need of a monitor/tv.  Of course it would be somewhat difficult to know when the queued content is downloaded.

**Gold Subscription:**  You do not want it.  Since you do not have internet connectivity to your Xbox you will not benefit from this subscription.

**Best Suggestion:** Get your games on disks.  You can check your local library if you can borrow some.  Otherwise Craigslist and eBay are some good sources for used games.